# XML Schema type that generates Java primitive type using JAXB doesn't add required to it

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd

I'm using JAXB(xjc version 2.2.4-2) to generate Java classes from a XML Schema. The XML types that map to a Java primitive datatype don't add:

```
@XmlElement(required = true)
```

For example when using:

```
<element name="userId" type="long"/>
<element name="userName" type="string"/>
```

will result in:

```
//no annotation added here
protected long userId;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String userName;
```

Does anyone have an explanation why this happens?

Does any of this have to do with options that you can set with xjc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need an annotation to show that a property of Java type `long` is required as this is implicit from the fact that primitive values can't be null.  A non-nillable required element of type `xs:long` maps to Java `long`, an optional or nillable one maps to `java.lang.Long` (which permits `null`, representing absent or `xsi:nil` as appropriate).

An element that is *both* optional *and* nillable (odd, but allowed by XML Schema) would map to a `JAXBElement<Long>` to distinguish between absent (a `null` `JAXBElement`) and nil (a non-null `JAXBElement` whose `isNil()` returns true).

Comment: I last did a SOAP test and found that the schema, which had an elemtent of type unsignedShort (with implicit minOccurs="1" --> thus required), didn't validate correctly. I could leave that one empty in my request, though it was required.

Comment: @JonathanRamos An `<xs:element name="foo" type="xs:unsignedShort" />` should map to a property of type `int` with `@XmlSchemaType(name = "unsignedShort")` and _without_ `@XmlElement(required = true)`, I've just tested that locally and it works fine for me.

Comment: Ian, well that's why I deleted it. When I just tested again it worked normally. So I probably did something wrong there.

Comment: I just found out what I did. I had done:
`code`<element name="userNumber" type="unsignedShort" minOccurs="0"/>
Which leads to:

    @XmlSchemaType(name = "unsignedShort")
    protected Integer userNumber;

Comment: @JonathanRamos yes, that's the same principle - it uses the wrapper type for something that can be `null` and the primitive type for things that can't.

Comment: I just tested against the primitive `int`. I created an object which I marshalled to xml. When doing so, without setting a value for the int, it comes with:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UserType xmlns="http://www.example.org/vb">
    <userId>111</userId>
    <userName>John Doe</userName>
    <userNumber>0</userNumber>
</UserType>`

So it defaults *userNumber* to 0 , which is logical, but somewhat unwanted because the request was actually empty, as in `null` like you explained.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind a BigInteger in your java class you could use type="integer" or type="positiveInteger" (negative userId?). Your validation will work this way at a certain cost.

Another option would be to use jaxb custom bindings. Your element could be:

```
<element name="userId" type="long"/>
```

and your have to create an extra binding file e.g.

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" 
  xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" 
  jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="my.xsd" node="//xs:element[@name='UserType']//xs:element[@name='userId']">
 <jxb:property>
  <jxb:baseType name="java.lang.Long" />
 </jxb:property>
</jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Now you can call xjc like: xjc my.xsd -b my.xjb

This results in:

`@XmlElement(required = true, type = Long.class)
 protected Integer userId;`

Comment: This does indeed create and object `Long`:

`@XmlElement(required = true, type = Long.class) protected Long userId;'

Which doesn't let me send a request with that field being empty. Still don't understand, why adding a minOccurs=1 to for example: type="long" doesn't create a `Long` immediately. It feels like a design flaw in JAXB.

Comment: Agree, if xjc would create object types instead of primitives this would be more consistent