# JAXB compiler is binding xs:long to Java Long instead of primitive long class

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I am generating sources from WSDL. It generate wrapper types. I want JAXB to generate primitive types instead of wrappers.

In pom.xml

```
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-stubs</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceType>wsdl</sourceType>
                            <sources>
                                <source>
                                    ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/my.wsdl
                                </source>
                            </sources>
                            <clearOutputDir>true</clearOutputDir>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution> 
</plugin>
```

In my WSDL file

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="initBal" type="xs:long"/>
```

In generated class

```
protected Long initBal;
```

I tried to set a bindingDirectory to force to use primitive instead of wrappers. But seems that option is not available with jaxb2-maven-plugin 2.5.0 version.

```
<configuration>
                            <sourceType>wsdl</sourceType>
                            <sources>
                                <source>
                                    ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/my.wsdl
                                </source>
                            </sources>
                            <clearOutputDir>true</clearOutputDir>
                            <xjbSources>
                                <xjbSource>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/aBindingConfiguration.xjb</xjbSource>
                            </xjbSources>
                        </configuration>
```

aBindingConfiguration.xjb file

```
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1">
    <jaxws:bindings xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">
        <jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>false</jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>
    </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Comment: Look at https://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.5.0/xjc-mojo.html for available configuration. And bindingDirectory is not listed.

Comment: bindingDirectory seems not available in 2.x alternative options is not clear

Comment: What are your intention using bindingDirectory?

Comment: I want JAXB to generate primitive types instead of wrappers.

Comment: I assume you did not search Stackoverflow previously for your question.  Because I found your answer in another Stackoverflow question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801401/xml-schema-type-that-generates-java-primitive-type-using-jaxb-doesnt-add-requir by Looking for jaxb generate primitives. You have to remove minOccurs="0" which indicates a nullable value.

Comment: I can't change the WSDL. I update the question with xjb config. But still JAXB generate wrapper types.

Comment: You can not use primitive type for nullable value because primitives are not nullable.

Comment: As Katt indicted by setting minOccurs="0" JAXB generate primitive type. By setting default="0" in WSDL possible to set a default value for wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can not use primitive type for nullable value because primitives are not nullable. You have to remove minOccurs="0" which indicates a nullable value.

look at [XML Schema type that generates Java primitive type using JAXB doesn't add required to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801401/xml-schema-type-that-generates-java-primitive-type-using-jaxb-doesnt-add-requir)

But looking further I found a setting for JAXB bindings which is not described for the official Customize JAXB Bindings https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/custom.html

```
optionalProperty="primitive"
```

look at https://download.oracle.com/javaee-archive/jaxb.java.net/users/2011/05/10121.html and  [JAXB compiler is binding xs:boolean to Java Boolean wrapper class, instead of boolean primitive type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035975/jaxb-compiler-is-binding-xsboolean-to-java-boolean-wrapper-class-instead-of-bo)

Also you could try using JAXB binding for additional methods to ask for value state

```
 generateIsSetMethod = "true"
```